How to render HTML links in Flutter?
I am doing an experiment where the goal is to render Flutter Dart code into HTML.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HtmlLikeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('HTML-like Elements in Flutter'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // H1
            Text(
              'This is H1',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // H2
            Text(
              'This is H2',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // H3
            Text(
              'This is H3',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // H4
            Text(
              'This is H4',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // Paragraph with strong and em
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'This is a paragraph with ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'strong',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(text: ' and '),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'emphasized',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(text: ' text.'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // Blockquote
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              child: Text(
                'This is a blockquote. It is used to indicate the quotation of a large section of text from another source.',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // Unordered List
            Text(
              'Unordered List:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                BulletPoint(text: 'First item'),
                BulletPoint(text: 'Second item'),
                BulletPoint(text: 'Third item'),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // Ordered List
            Text(
              'Ordered List:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                NumberedPoint(number: 1, text: 'First item'),
                NumberedPoint(number: 2, text: 'Second item'),
                NumberedPoint(number: 3, text: 'Third item'),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // Image
            Image.network(
              'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // URL/Link
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                // Handle URL tap
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      content: Text('Link tapped!'),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Text(
                'Click here to open a URL',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blue),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // Code Block
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Text(
                'print("Hello, World!");',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.green, fontFamily: 'Courier'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BulletPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  BulletPoint({required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            '• ',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberedPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  final String text;

  NumberedPoint({required this.number, required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            '$number. ',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I know flutter web has an html web-renderer.
fvm flutter build web --web-renderer html --csp

It renders the following Html code.


<flt-scene-host style="pointer-events: none;">
  <flt-scene style="position: absolute;">
    <flt-transform style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: none;">
      <flt-clip clip-type="rect" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 629px; height: 993px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;">
        <flt-clip-interior style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
          <flt-offset style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
            <flt-picture aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"></flt-picture>
            <flt-offset style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
              <flt-offset style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: translate(0px, 56px);">
                <flt-offset style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
                  <flt-offset style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
                    <flt-picture aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
                      <flt-canvas style="position: absolute; transform: translate(15px, 15px);">
                        <flt-paragraph style="position: absolute; white-space: pre; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1); left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 70.12px; line-height: 45.75px;">This</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 70.12px; width: 9.63px; line-height: 45.75px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 79.75px; width: 27px; line-height: 45.75px;">is</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 106.75px; width: 9.63px; line-height: 45.75px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 116.38px; width: 39.6px; line-height: 45.75px;">H1</flt-span>
                        </flt-paragraph>
                        <flt-paragraph style="position: absolute; white-space: pre; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 56.75); left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 61.48px; line-height: 40.0312px;">This</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 61.48px; width: 8.45px; line-height: 40.0312px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 69.93px; width: 23.68px; line-height: 40.0312px;">is</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 93.61px; width: 8.45px; line-height: 40.0312px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 102.06px; width: 40.4px; line-height: 40.0312px;">H2</flt-span>
                        </flt-paragraph>
                        <flt-paragraph style="position: absolute; white-space: pre; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 106.781); left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 52.84px; line-height: 34.3125px;">This</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 52.84px; width: 7.28px; line-height: 34.3125px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 60.12px; width: 20.37px; line-height: 34.3125px;">is</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 80.49px; width: 7.28px; line-height: 34.3125px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 87.77px; width: 34.8px; line-height: 34.3125px;">H3</flt-span>
                        </flt-paragraph>
                        <flt-paragraph style="position: absolute; white-space: pre; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 151.094); left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 44.2px; line-height: 28.5938px;">This</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 44.2px; width: 6.11px; line-height: 28.5938px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 50.31px; width: 17.06px; line-height: 28.5938px;">is</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 67.37px; width: 6.11px; line-height: 28.5938px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 73.48px; width: 30.32px; line-height: 28.5938px;">H4</flt-span>
                        </flt-paragraph>
                        <flt-paragraph style="position: absolute; white-space: pre; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 189.688); left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 30.23px; line-height: 18px;">This</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 30.23px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;"> </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 34.68px; width: 11.55px; line-height: 18px;">is</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 46.23px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;"> </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 50.68px; width: 8.9px; line-height: 18px;">a</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 59.58px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;"> </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 64.03px; width: 72.95px; line-height: 18px;">paragraph</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 136.98px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;"> </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 141.43px; width: 28.45px; line-height: 18px;">with</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 169.88px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;"> </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 174.33px; width: 49.77px; line-height: 18px;">strong</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 224.1px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;"> </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 228.55px; width: 26.7px; line-height: 18px;">and</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 255.25px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;"> </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-style: italic; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 259.7px; width: 86.27px; line-height: 18px;">emphasized</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 345.97px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;"> </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 350.42px; width: 25.79px; line-height: 18px;">text</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 376.21px; width: 4.45px; line-height: 18px;">.</flt-span>
                        </flt-paragraph>
                        <draw-rect style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 217.688); width: 597px; height: 77.75px; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);"></draw-rect>
                        <flt-paragraph style="position: absolute; white-space: pre; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 17, 233.688); left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 35.56px; line-height: 22.875px;">This</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 35.56px; width: 4.94px; line-height: 22.875px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 40.5px; width: 13.75px; line-height: 22.875px;">is</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 54.25px; width: 4.94px; line-height: 22.875px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 59.19px; width: 11.08px; line-height: 22.875px;">a</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 70.27px; width: 4.94px; line-height: 22.875px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 75.21px; width: 96.58px; line-height: 22.875px;">blockquote</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 171.79px; width: 8.64px; line-height: 22.875px;">. </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 180.43px; width: 11.38px; line-height: 22.875px;">It</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 191.81px; width: 4.94px; line-height: 22.875px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 196.75px; width: 13.75px; line-height: 22.875px;">is</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 210.5px; width: 4.94px; line-height: 22.875px;">
                          </flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 215.44px; width: 41.27px; line-height: 22.875px;">used</flt-span>
                          <flt-span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: Comfortaa_regular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.25px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 256.71px; width: 4.94px; line-height: 22.875px;">
                          </flt-span>



Now the next step of my challenge is to use this LinkText widget and do whatever it takes to render it as real HTML Links. (The <a></a> tag )
class LinkText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final bool? isHovered;
  final FontWeight? fontWeight;
  final double? fontSize;
  final Color hoveredColor;
  final Color color;
  final bool underline;
  final GestureTapCallback? onTap;
  final TextOverflow? overflow;
  const LinkText(
    this.text, {
    Key? key,
    this.isHovered,
    this.fontWeight,
    this.onTap,
    this.overflow,
    this.hoveredColor = Colors.blue,
    this.color = Colors.white,
    this.underline = false,
    this.fontSize,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: HoverBuilder(builder: (hovering) {
        final isHovered = this.isHovered ?? hovering;
        return Text(
          text,
          overflow: overflow,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: this.fontSize ?? 13,
            fontFamily: 'Recoleta',
            fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.w200,
            color: isHovered ? hoveredColor : color,
            decoration: underline ? TextDecoration.underline : null,
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

If I were to do it manually, my plan is to write a Javascript code that watches the DOM for some identifier (that lets the Javascript code know that this html block is supposed to be an Html Link), find a way to extract and parse the URL link, and wrap the generated element into the <a></a> tag but I have 3 issues.

How pass such identifier to rendered HTML code ?

Is this approach over-complicated ? Is there a built-in Flutter Web hidden feature that can make my life easier ?

Finally, is the Flutter Web Generated HTML code through the Web-renderer documented and supported ? If so, where can I find such documentation ? Or it is an internal API that is not supposed to be programmed like what I am trying to do and can break in future Flutter release ?


